# Issue with JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, environment-variables

i am trying to run sonar runner, i have the bat file in my project directory and when i navigate to it via command promptt and try and run it i get an error message saying

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home
>   folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found there.

If i echo the path of Java_Home it is pointing too

> $C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin

Is this path correct or does it need to be changed?

Thanks

Comment: I think Java home is without bin, but then you need to add %java_home%/bin to your path varible

Comment: The JAVA_HOME exists, and I've tried all combinations to set its path i.e. jdk, jre, jdk/bin, jre/ and jre/bin. Still, I get the same error when I run sonar-runner.bat. I've also removed all traces of older JDKs in my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should point to the java root folder, in your case to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15`

Answer (score 2):

Please Restrict your path to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15` only (i.e. no bin).

Answer (score 1):

Given that it's looking for `\bin\java.exe` *within* `JAVA_HOME`, I suspect you ought to set it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_15` - without the `bin` part.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Stuff

**[Configure Java environment on Windows](http://vietpad.sourceforge.net/javaonwindows.html)**