# SONAR in Jenkins - "can't find \bin\java.exe" (2015)

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

For some reason Sonar can't find the java.exe.
Don't have in my [JAVA_HOME semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441829/issue-with-java-home)...

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home
       folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found there.
```

env variable:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71
```

of course I have under this folder the "\bin\java.exe"...

When I take the command line from Jenkins console and run it in CMD it seems to work (have failures within sonar logic around my project which is ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the job configuration level do you have the option of multiple JDK's? If it's set to default, change it to JDK7

Comment: this is the exact reason, now it is working. Thanks!

Comment: Under a slave configuration I needed to set the JDK 7 "Home" value for that slave, if that helps anyone...