# How to setup sonarqube for angular 8 project

Tags: angular, sonarqube

I want to do a setup of sonarqube for my angular 8 projects. I have googled so many things for the same but not getting the exact steps. It will help if anyone guides me for the same.

Comment: [Check this](https://medium.com/@learning.bikash/angular-code-coverage-with-sonarqube-d2283442080b)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale . thanks for the link.i have gone through the links already and tried the steps given into it. Getting error while running the npm run sonar:ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found there.

Comment: [Check this_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441829/issue-with-java-home)